# Getting gawk to search for multiple strings and stop at the Nth match

Tags: string, awk

I have a large text file like this:

```
1
           Power History Table  ( 23-JUN-14 @ 10:48:39 )
  
                starting core loading  140619~a 
                   scan date and time  1406200700 
                  ending core loading  140622~a 

associated site L08 fission power   0.000000           0.000000             0.000
1                      flux detector measured values for scan of 140620 for sites: E22 P18 L06                     
                       flux detector simulated shape from core 140619~a for sites: e22 p18 l06                     
 
          -175.0    -140.0    -105.0     -70.0     -35.0       0.0      35.0      70.0     105.0     140.0     175.0   
 
    0.30E+15  .....................................................................................................  0.30E+15   
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .    e l  .   l     .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .     ee  l         .       e .l        .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .  e      .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .  l      .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .       e .         .         .         .       l .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .   p     .         .e        .         .         .
    0.24E+15  ........................................p....................p.......................................  0.24E+15   
              .         .         .    l    .  p      .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .       p .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .    p    .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .    p    .         .         .
              .         .       l .         .         .         .         .         .         e         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .P        .         .         .         .
    0.18E+15  ..................p..............P........................E..........................................  0.18E+15   
              .         .         .         .     E   .      L  .         .L        .         .  l      .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .  p      .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .    P    .         .         .
              .         .         .         .  L      .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .e        .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .l        .         .         P         .   L     .       L .         .       e .         .
    0.12E+15  ...........p............................L............................................................  0.12E+15   
              .         .       L .    P    .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .    L    .         .         .         .         .         .         l         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         p         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .  L      P         .
              .         .       P .         .         .         .         .         .         .         L         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .P        .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .L        .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
    0.60E+14  .....................................................................................................  0.60E+14   
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .       E .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
              .         .         .       E .      E  .    E    .         .         .E        E         .         .
     0.0      ......................................................E........E....P................................   0.0       
 
          -175.0    -140.0    -105.0     -70.0     -35.0       0.0      35.0      70.0     105.0     140.0     175.0   
 
                                                 detector elevations 
1


 scan 140620 fission power at tpd 159258.0   total power   99.270

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...      ...   1.439   1.255     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...      ...   1.475     ...   1.185     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...     ...    1.383     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.371     ...     ...   1.378     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.373    0.904   1.716     ...   0.721     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...   1.178      ...   1.052   0.864     ...     ...   0.594     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...    0.895     ...   0.281     ...     ...     ...     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   1.173   1.766   1.350     ...   0.614     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.347      ...   1.334     ...     ...   0.676   1.231     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.726   1.713     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   1.053   0.953    1.395   0.329     ...   1.337   0.790     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.178    1.145     ...     ...   0.338   1.062     ...   1.273     ...    18
 17          ...   0.602   1.018    1.552   1.548   1.479     ...     ...   1.260     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.377   0.767   1.206     ...    16
 15          ...   1.231     ...    0.167   0.319     ...   0.315   0.803     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...    1.336     ...   1.429   1.600     ...   1.245   1.381     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   0.876    0.314   1.567   1.726   1.261     ...   1.379     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.518      ...   0.164     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...   1.435   0.971      ...   1.316   1.366     ...     ...   1.483     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   1.007   1.174   1.048     ...   1.343     ...            10
  9          ...     ...     ...    0.748     ...   1.227   0.759     ...     ...     ...         9
  8              ...   1.375      ...     ...   0.957     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.212      ...     ...   0.793   0.647   1.264     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.048     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.205     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.140     ...   1.279     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...     ...   1.113   1.075     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         23-JUN-14  10:47:46
1


 scan 140620 power-to-coolant at tpd 159258.0   total power   92.730

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...      ...   1.346   1.174     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...      ...   1.379     ...   1.108     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...     ...    1.293     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.282     ...     ...   1.288     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.284    0.845   1.605     ...   0.674     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...   1.102      ...   0.983   0.808     ...     ...   0.556     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...    0.837     ...   0.246     ...     ...     ...     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   1.097   1.652   1.262     ...   0.574     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.260      ...   1.248     ...     ...   0.632   1.151     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.614   1.602     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   0.985   0.891    1.305   0.288     ...   1.250   0.739     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.102    1.071     ...     ...   0.296   0.993     ...   1.190     ...    18
 17          ...   0.599   0.952    1.451   1.447   1.383     ...     ...   1.178     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.287   0.718   1.127     ...    16
 15          ...   1.151     ...    0.146   0.279     ...   0.276   0.751     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...    1.249     ...   1.336   1.497     ...   1.164   1.292     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   0.819    0.275   1.466   1.614   1.179     ...   1.290     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.419      ...   0.144     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...   1.342   0.908      ...   1.231   1.278     ...     ...   1.387     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   0.941   1.098   0.980     ...   1.255     ...            10
  9          ...     ...     ...    0.699     ...   1.147   0.710     ...     ...     ...         9
  8              ...   1.286      ...     ...   0.895     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.133      ...     ...   0.741   0.605   1.181     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   0.980     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.126     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.066     ...   1.196     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...     ...   1.040   1.005     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

I'm trying to use Gawk to search the file and extract the line:  scan date and time  1406200700  and the fission power map to another text file.

So the output should look something like this:

```
scan date and time  1406200700

 scan 140620 fission power at tpd 159258.0   total power   99.270

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...      ...   1.439   1.255     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...      ...   1.475     ...   1.185     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...     ...    1.383     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.371     ...     ...   1.378     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.373    0.904   1.716     ...   0.721     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...   1.178      ...   1.052   0.864     ...     ...   0.594     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...    0.895     ...   0.281     ...     ...     ...     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   1.173   1.766   1.350     ...   0.614     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.347      ...   1.334     ...     ...   0.676   1.231     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.726   1.713     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   1.053   0.953    1.395   0.329     ...   1.337   0.790     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.178    1.145     ...     ...   0.338   1.062     ...   1.273     ...    18
 17          ...   0.602   1.018    1.552   1.548   1.479     ...     ...   1.260     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.377   0.767   1.206     ...    16
 15          ...   1.231     ...    0.167   0.319     ...   0.315   0.803     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...    1.336     ...   1.429   1.600     ...   1.245   1.381     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   0.876    0.314   1.567   1.726   1.261     ...   1.379     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.518      ...   0.164     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...   1.435   0.971      ...   1.316   1.366     ...     ...   1.483     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   1.007   1.174   1.048     ...   1.343     ...            10
  9          ...     ...     ...    0.748     ...   1.227   0.759     ...     ...     ...         9
  8              ...   1.375      ...     ...   0.957     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.212      ...     ...   0.793   0.647   1.264     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.048     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.205     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.140     ...   1.279     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...     ...   1.113   1.075     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

My gawk command is:

`gawk '/scan date and time/ && /fission power at tpd/ { 2;/ y   z   a   b   c/q;p;}' input.txt >> output.txt`

But it doesn't seem to work, gawk just freezes and I have to Ctl-C to get out of it.  I want gawk to stop at the second occurrence of the "y   z   a   b   c"  column headings, not the first.  But I think my syntax is wrong.

And I'm not sure if I should be using the && to search for two different strings.  I've also tried || and that didn't work either.  Using the "," just gives me everything between "scan date and time" and "Fission power at tpd", which I don't want.

Comment: If you create a much smaller example then more people will be able to take the much shorter time to understand it to be able to help you.

Comment: you can't nest regex matching inside of `{ ... }`. you'll need to use `{if ($0 ~ / y   z   a   b   c/) {print "matched " $0}....`(that's the rough idea, anyway). Not clear about the rest of your problem, as above..... Although written about `bash` scripting the   section **How to turn a bad script into a good question** in [BashInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) is good advice for any language to pare down your problem. Often when you used this approach, the source of the problem becomes obvious to you.. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you can switch to mult-line processing by using `BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}`. You can search here for other examples of using that. Hm.. see that you have numerous section of `\n\n` delimited data. Can you change the output of your source? Or maybe `RS=ORS="\n\n\n"` (3-lines) might work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
awk '
     BEGIN { 
             prnt=0 # set print marker to 0 to begin with
           } 
    /scan date and time/ { 
             print # print when we see the "first scan date and time"
           } 
    /scan.*fission power/ { 
             prnt=1 # When we see the scan .. line begin print and so set print marker to 1
           } 
    /(y   z   a   b)/ { 
             fin++ # There is a y z a.... at the beginning of the required output and so set a counter
           } 
    /([[:digit:]]+\:){2}[[:digit:]]+/ && fin==2 { 
             prnt=0 # When we see a line with a time and y z a... has printed twice, set the print marker to 0 to stop the printing
           } prnt' file
```

One liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { prnt=0 } /scan date and time/ { print } /scan.*fission power/ { prnt=1 } /(y   z   a   b)/ { fin++} /([[:digit:]]+\:){2}[[:digit:]]+/ && fin==2 { prnt=0 } prnt' file
```

Comment: Thanks.  

Your solution almost works, but I get the power-to-coolant map underneath the fission power map in the resulting output files.  I tried fixing it by changing /scan.*fission power/ to /fission power at tpd/ but it still gives me the power-to-coolant map as well.

It doesn't seem to stop at the second occurrence of y   z   a   b   c.

Comment: It works when I tested it with the sample you gave. Are you using a different file?